# Unable to load save games in Fallout 4 on Steam; save files missing

Tags: fallout-4

I bought *Fallout 4* on Steam, and I have noticed that although I get the message that games are being saved or auto-saved, when I want to load a game, there is none, and in no folder.

I already deactivated my Steam cloud, deleted and redownloaded the game, and disabled firewall things and that. That's what they told me on several forums, but none of it worked. I have also tried running the game outside of Steam as an administrator, to no avail. My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Just to be clear: you are not using mods?

Comment: And have you checked the *Steam\userdata\<yourID>\377160\ac\WinMyDocuments\My Games\Fallout4\Saves* folder? Are there any files there?

Comment: Your question notes that the auto saves are disappearing, are manual saves disappearing as well? If so, are they disappearing immediately (after you save, if you go to load, there's no options?), or only after closing/restarting game?